# How to change the order of div elements dynamically in angular?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have multiple div elements in my form. I have to reorder my div elements dynamically in UI by drag and drop

For ex : below is my 6 div elements

```
<div>Div1</div>
<div>Div2</div>
<div>Div3</div>
<div>Div4</div>
<div>Div5</div>
<div>Div6</div>
```

I want to change the order of div by drag and drop. For ex : I have to put the 6th div into 2nd position, similarly 4th into 1st and so on. i Couldn't able to find out how to change the position of div. Can anyone help to achieve this

Comment: Are you binding your HTML to a model? It might help if you show your actual code.

Comment: https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview

Answer (score 3):

With css you can use flex.

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.box :nth-child(1) { order: 2; }
.box :nth-child(2) { order: 3; }
.box :nth-child(3) { order: 1; }
.box :nth-child(4) { order: 3; }
.box :nth-child(5) { order: 1; }
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Ordering_Flex_Items

To ordering by drag & drop there is the jquery option :

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable

```
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT 1**

Now that you've edited your title for angular, here's a drag&drop link
https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview#reordering-lists

Comment: can we do the same in bootstrap any default classes there

Comment: To ordering yes https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes, but there is no data-attributes to drag and drop.